# wget - How do I download webpages based on URL Pattern?

Tags: linux, wget, curl

Consider a website www.music.com with the following directory structure:

```
/piano
   /covers
     /Chopin 
        apple.html
        bannan.js
        balloon.html
        index.html
     /Franz Liszt
        index.html
        roses.js
        Love Dream.html

     /Frodo
        index.html
        linkenso.html

/violin
   /covers
      /David
         Viva.html
      /Ross
         index.html
```

I only want to get the index.html files from the nested directory in music.com/piano/covers where the name of the subdirecory starts with "Fr". In example above, I only want to download 2 files :

- www.music.com/piano/covers/Franz Listz/ index.html
- www.music.com/piano/covers/Frodo/ index.html

Using wget, I thought of using the following:

```
$ wget 
   --mirror 
   --header="Accept: text/html"  
   --page-requisites 
   --html-extension 
   --convert-links 
   --restrict-file-names=windows 
   --domains=www.music.com/piano/covers 
   --accept-regex=/piano/covers/Fr.*/index.html  
        http://www.music.com
```

I executed the same on my own website, but I only get one incorrect file:

`www.music.com/index.html`

**Why did I use the options above?**

1. Using `--recursive` or `-r` is not the problem as the error still
   persists. Furthermore, the option `--page-requisites` is much better
   alternative as I am not demanding every piece of information from
   the server.
2. `--domains` : Ensures that nothing outside of the
   specified URL is downloaded. This should be the case as I don't need
   any resource outside the `piano/covers` folder
3. `--header`: I want to override the Accept : * / * to prevent my request from demanding everything
4. `--html-extensions`: Only download html files

It seems like the `--accept-regex` part isn't even considered for some reason. But it is recommended over `-A` option as the files I need are spanned across different directories. Any ideas how I can get the 2 files as specified by the `--accept-regex` argument?

**EDIT 1:**

Accessing the URL used in the example above gives a 404 error. So I will give context to my website which I am actually trying to perform this operation

From www.ajayhalthor.com, with the directory structure:

```
/piano
   /nightwish-sahara
   /nightwish-amaranth
   /skillet-hero
   /skillet-the-last-night
   /breaking-benjamin-diary-of-jane
   /skillet-comatose
   /one-republic-counting-stars
   /skillet-falling-inside-the-black
   /63/index.html
   /a/few/more/links/index.html

/about
   /other/links/index.html
/Home
   /main/links/index.html
```

From this structure, I want to retrieve the files in www.ajayhalthor.com/piano that start with "Sk". I expect to retrieve the following files:

- www.ajayhalthor.com/piano/skillet-hero
- www.ajayhalthor.com/piano/skillet-the-last-night
- www.ajayhalthor.com/piano/skillet-comatose
- www.ajayhalthor.com/piano/skillet-falling-inside-the-black

Running the following command:

```
$ wget 
   --mirror 
   --header="Accept: text/html"  
   --page-requisites 
   --html-extension 
   --convert-links 
   --restrict-file-names=windows 
   --domains=www.ajayhalthor.com/piano
   --accept-regex="piano/sk.*"
        http://www.ajayhalthor.com
```

I get the following output:

```
Resolving www.ajayhalthor.com (www.ajayhalthor.com)... 23.229.213.7
Connecting to www.ajayhalthor.com (www.ajayhalthor.com)|23.229.213.7|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘www.ajayhalthor.com/index.html’

www.ajayhalthor.com/index.html              [ <=>                                                                          ]  24.28K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2017-01-19 01:56:11 (245 KB/s) - ‘www.ajayhalthor.com/index.html’ saved [24862]

FINISHED --2017-01-19 01:56:11--
Total wall clock time: 1.4s
Downloaded: 1 files, 24K in 0.1s (245 KB/s)
Converting links in www.ajayhalthor.com/index.html... 11-1
Converted links in 1 files in 0.003 seconds.
```

Only 1 file www.ajayhalthor.com/index.html is downloaded.Am I using `--accept-regex` correctly?

Comment: Have you tried putting the regex in `"`s to prevent shell expansion? Also, try it without the .eading `/`: `--accept-regex="piano/covers/Fr.*/index.html"`

Comment: I added the quotations and eliminated the preceding slash, but the only thing that happens is the www.music.com/index.html file downloads (same output as in question)

Comment: Trying to access the files directly, in browser or `wget` returns 404 error, for all the listed `index.html` in your Q. Are the files there? And accessible?

Comment: I didn't disclose the true documents I am trying to access. Like I said, I tried the equivalent for my website. Should I modify my question for my exact website?

Comment: Either the exact website, or some sanitized copy you set up for testing. Can't see whats _not_ working when it's not there to work with.

Comment: I modified the question as per your request. Please see EDIT 1

Comment: `wget` can only follow links in pages downloaded. There a no links in the original index page that meet the regex so none are downloaded. It won't, as written, crawl the file structure looking for matches. need to use the FTP protocol for that functionality.